# Best way to queue jQuery plugins execution

Tags: jquery

I am combining the galleryView and fancybox plugins to load some image galleries on a page.

Everything is working fine but I have the feeling I have just been lucky...

This is what I do when the page loads:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Bind fancybox links with live 
    jQuery('a.fancybox').live('click', function(){
        jQuery.fancybox(this,{
            'easingIn'  :   'swing',
            'easingOut' :   'swing',
            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'           :   400, 
            'speedOut'          :   200, 
            'overlayShow'   :   true,
            'overlayOpacity'  : 0.8
        });

        return false;

    });

    //Load Galleryview
    jQuery('#current_gallery').galleryView({
        panel_width: 520,
        panel_height: 345,
        frame_width: 100,
        frame_height: 60,
        transition_interval: 999999999,//To keep the images still
        nav_theme: 'light',
        pause_on_hover: true
    });

});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Wrap full size image in 'a' tags
    jQuery('div.panel img').each(function(i){

        //Get full size image url
        var full_image_url = jQuery(this).attr('src'); 

        jQuery(this).wrap('<a href=' + full_image_url + ' class="fancybox" />')


    });

});
```

Basically I queue the execution calling two .ready() functions in sequence. Galleryview modifies the DOM and my second .ready() wraps elements from that modified DOM. It works, but am I following the right approach? I call this script to load other galleries using Ajax and again no problem...

Should I use something like this instead:

```
$(function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {

    //Wrap full size image in 'a' tags
jQuery('div.panel img').each(function(i){

//Get full size image url
var full_image_url = jQuery(this).attr('src'); 

jQuery(this).wrap('<a href=' + full_image_url + ' class="fancybox" />')

})}, 0);
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't put everything in the **same** ready handler. It doesn't really do any good to put them in separate handlers, because jQuery will just invoke them in sequence anyway.

Comment: I tried single and double handler, no difference at all. My worries are about the galleryview plugin internal script, which does not trigger any callback function on complete event. What happens if I have a lot of images per each gallery? Would $.wrap() wait until the DOM is ready again? I do not know.